# out.write runs several times but resulting file is empty

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

I am developing in Java SE on NetBeans 7.3.1 on Windows 7.

I am trying to write a set on numbers, one on each line, to an ASCII text file.

```
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(outputFileName, false); //false tells to not append data.
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            for (int i=0; i<numBins; ++i){
                String str=Integer.toString(hist[i]);
                str.concat("\n");
                out.write(str);
            }
            br.close();
```

numBins is 6 and the program runs through without any errors. I check tih the debugger and

```
 out.write(str);
```

is called 6 times.  hist[i] are small integral numbers.  For some reason, the resulting file is empty and of zero size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close your BufferedWriter Object

```
 FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(outputFileName, false); //false tells to not append data.
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            for (int i=0; i<numBins; ++i){
                String str=Integer.toString(hist[i]);
                str.concat("\n");
                out.write(str);
            }
            out.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call close method on your BufferedWriter object to flush the contents to file:

```
   FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(outputFileName, false); //false tells to not append data.
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            for (int i=0; i<numBins; ++i){
                String str=Integer.toString(hist[i]);
                str.concat("\n");
                out.write(str);
            }
           // add this also
           out.close();
```